# SQL Server 2008 FactFinance primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I have a problem with this script

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[tables] 
               WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FactFinance]') 
                 AND OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactFinance]
    (
        [FinanceKey] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        [TimeKey] [int] NULL,
        [OrganizationKey] [int] NULL,
        [DepartmentGroupKey] [int] NULL,
        [ScenarioKey] [int] NULL,
        [AccountKey] [int] NULL,
        [Amount] [float] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY];  
END
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
```

When I run this, I get this result:

## [image]

but if I remove this line `[Finance Key] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`, from the script, it works

Comment: `IDENTITY` requires a seed and increment value. For example `IDENTITY (1,1)` (Seed of 1, increment of 1). The Documentation helps you here: [`CREATE TABLE` (Transact-SQL) `IDENTITY` (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That's an answer @Larnu :)

Comment: @scsimon just noticed that, actually, the documentation states *"You must specify both the seed and increment or neither. If neither is specified, the default is (1,1). "* (I always thought it was mandatory). Tested on a 2008 server as well and `CREATE TABLE test(ID [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);` works fine. We really need the error message here. Either way, however, it's poor practice to omit the seed and increment values.

Comment: Do you put something in the `identity column`? You want it to be automatically increased? @renard iane

Comment: By any chance did you map something to your FinanceKey in your ssis component? If you did, please remove it. Its an increment key, so it add values automatically and cannot be assigned